# Http Delete not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, reactjs

I added this on my api department conrtoller however when I run it the website says that it is not found, I am not familiar with c# any help with do..

```
 [HttpDelete]
         public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Remove([FromBody] Department tObj, [FromUri]bool? tagAsDeleteOnly)
        {
        _bll.Delete(tObj, tagAsDeleteOnly ?? true);

        var result = await _bll.Save();

        return Ok(new WebResult
        {
            Data = tObj,
            Total = (int)result,
            Result = result > 0
        });
    }
```

the error says

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8933/api/Department/Remove'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Department' that matches the request."
}
```

Request Payload

```
{Key: 18, Users: null, Projects: null, Status: null, Code: "ppp", Name: "lll", IsActive: true,…}
Code:"ppp"
IsActive:true
Key:18
Name:"lll"
Projects:null
State:2
Status:null
StatusMessage:null
Users:null
```

this is the front end (REACTJS)

```
delete(form) {
    debugger
    form.State = 2;
    let id = form.Key;
    this.props.deleter('department/Remove', form);}
```

then it proceeds to this ajax

```
export const deleter = (url, params) => {
    return(dispatch, getState, api) => {
            api += 'api/';
        return fetch(`${api}${url}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => dispatch(departmentResult(result, types.DELETER)));
    }
}
```

Im not sure why it wasn't reading the controller because the other controller besides remove is working..

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as below;

```
        [HttpDelete("{tagAsDeletedOnly?}")]       
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Remove([FromBody] Department tObj, [FromRoute]bool? tagAsDeleteOnly) // use FromRoute
        {
            _bll.Delete(tObj, tagAsDeleteOnly ?? true);

            var result = await _bll.Save();

            return Ok(new WebResult
            {
                Data = tObj,
                Total = (int)result,
                Result = result > 0
            });
        }
```